# Code jam Store Credit

Tags: c#

**Problem**
You receive a credit C at a local store and would like to buy two items. You first walk through the store and create a list L of all available items. From this list you would like to buy two items that add up to the entire value of the credit. The solution you provide will consist of the two integers indicating the positions of the items in your list (smaller number first).

**Input**
The first line of input gives the number of cases, N. N test cases follow. For each test case there will be:
•   One line containing the value C, the amount of credit you have at the store.
•   One line containing the value I, the number of items in the store.
•   One line containing a space separated list of I integers. Each integer P indicates the price of an item in the store.
•   Each test case will have exactly one solution.

**Output**
For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: " followed by the indices of the two items whose price adds up to the store credit. The lower index should be output first.
Limits
5 ≤ C ≤ 1000
1 ≤ P ≤ 1000
Small dataset
N = 10
3 ≤ I ≤ 100
Large dataset
N = 50
3 ≤ I ≤ 2000

**Sample Data**
Input

3
100
3
5 75 25
200
7
150 24 79 50 88 345 3
8
8
2 1 9 4 4 56 90 3

Output 
Case #1: 2 3
Case #2: 1 4
Case #3: 4 5

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadCreaditCard
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ask for input file path.
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the input file path:");
            //@"C:\Users\NIRBHAY\Document\Store Credit-small.txt";
            string path = Console.ReadLine();

            //validate the file path.
            while (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid file path:");
                path = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            //open the file to read the data.
            using (StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                //read the no of cases.
                string noOfCases = tr.ReadLine();
                int caseCounter = 0;

                //validate if first line of input file is valid numeric value.
                while (!int.TryParse(noOfCases, out caseCounter))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("First line of input file is not a numeric value.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric value:");
                    noOfCases = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                int caseNo = 1;
                //read all the lines of data and show it in reverse order.
                while (caseCounter-- > 0)
                {
                    #region Read credit value
                    string creditStr = tr.ReadLine();
                    if (creditStr == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input file.");
                        break;
                    }
                    int creditValue = 0;
                    if (!int.TryParse(creditStr, out creditValue))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input file.");
                        break;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Read items count
                    string itemsCountStr = tr.ReadLine();
                    if (itemsCountStr == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input file.");
                        break;
                    }

                    int itemsCount = 0;
                    if (!int.TryParse(itemsCountStr, out itemsCount))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input file.");
                        break;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    string itemsPriceStr = tr.ReadLine();
                    if (itemsPriceStr == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input file.");
                        break;
                    }
                    string[] arrayOfCosts = itemsPriceStr.Split(' ');
                    PrintItems(caseNo, creditValue, itemsCount, arrayOfCosts);
                    caseNo++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n \n Press any key to exit :)");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prints the indexes of selected items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="caseNo"></param>
        /// <param name="creditValue"></param>
        /// <param name="itemsCount"></param>
        /// <param name="arrayOfCosts"></param>
        private static void PrintItems(int caseNo, int creditValue, int itemsCount, string[] arrayOfCosts)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
            {
                int firstItemCost = int.Parse(arrayOfCosts[i]);
                for (int j = i + 1; j < itemsCount; j++)
                {
                    int secondItemCost = int.Parse(arrayOfCosts[j]);
                    if (firstItemCost + secondItemCost == creditValue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Case#{0}: {1}, {2}", caseNo, i, j);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```